# How to keep the last plotted line2D always the same color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I am coding a program where the user can over plot functions on a defined axis. Is there any way such that the last plotted function is always a fixed color (let's say green)?

For instance, the code below takes as input the degree of a polynomial and plots all the polynomials of same and lower degree. I would like a tweak such as the **last** plot (in this case the polynomial of highest degree) is always green:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_polynomials(highest_degree):

    x = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
    for degree in np.arange(1,highest_degree+1):
        coefficients = np.repeat(1,degree)
        label = 'degree={}'.format(degree)
        polynomial = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, coefficients)
        plt.plot(x, polynomial, label=label)

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

plot_polynomials(6)
```

Looking forward to the comments!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
def plot_polynomials(highest_degree):

    x = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
    for degree in np.arange(1,highest_degree+1):
        coefficients = np.repeat(1,degree)
        label = 'degree={}'.format(degree)
        colors=plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
        colors.pop(2) #Removing green from color cycle
        polynomial = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, coefficients)
        if degree==highest_degree:
            plt.plot(x, polynomial, label=label, color='g', lw=3)
        else:
            plt.plot(x, polynomial, label=label, color=colors[degree-1])
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

plot_polynomials(6)
```

Output:

[image]

Note: made the line thicker with `lw`, but that's obviously optional

Edit: Removed green from the color cycle, so there's only one green line